# How to set scrollView scrollBy sensor x, y?

Tags: android, scrollview, accelerometer

I want, that srcollView scrolling by motion sensor y, x. If I tilt my device up it scrols up, if I tilt my device down, scrollView scroll down.

Is it possible? Sorry if my question is stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. `ScrollView` has multiple methods to scroll by `x` and `y` along with `z` and the [motion sensors tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) shows you how to track the user tilting the device. It's up to you though to turn the output from the accelerometer or gravity sensor into those x and y inputs to scroll by.